# How do I find out the contents of GDT

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address, protected-mode, gdt

I am analyzing a disassembled dll and got stuck on the line

```
mov ebx,fs:[00000004h]
```

I want to find out the exact physical address of the data that is written into ebx with this instruction. gdb tells me that `fs = 0x53.`

I already found out that the address depends on the mode (protected or real), and I'm pretty sure the CPU is in protected mode (see ***). So the start of segment fs should be stored somewhere in the GDT, right? I also found out the address of the `GDT-register (0x009bd5c0007f)`, but gdb doesn't let me access or read the register, so I don't know how to find out the physical address of fs (and, therefore, of `fs:[00000004h]`).

Can anybody help me please?

I used the instruction `smsw ax`, and after that `eax` was 0x280031. So the last bit is 1, which means protected mode. Did I get that right?

Comment: huh? Dynamic-link Library?

Comment: If this is 32-bit code it's probably reading from the [TIB/TEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's protected mode.

And you probably found the virtual address of the `GDT` by using the `SGDT` instruction.

That address, however, is unlikely to be useful since you can read the memory at that address only from code executing in the OS kernel (could be a kernel mode driver).

You need to find a way to read the memory of interest from inside the kernel.

Comment: sounds like something way beyond my abilities ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mentioning a DLL, I assume it's all on Windows. On Windows, `FS` is known to point at the thread information block (TIB). At offset 4, there's the pointer to the top of stack. The code loads it into `EBX`, that's it.

The value of FS does not matter, nor you need to poke around GDT. It's a documented part of the API.